# Is confounding a source of Type I errors?

Tags: statistical-significance, confounding, type-i-and-ii-errors

I would be interested to explore the potential sources of Type I errors in randomised controlled trials. A key question in this respect is whether confounding can be understood as one such source.

Comment: If the randomized controlled trial is successful, then there is no confounding, so how could it be a source of error?

Comment: @ Noah Your notion of "successful" invites some exploration. Use of simple randomisation does not ipso facto irradicate confounding.

Answer (score 1):

Confounding can result in the identification of spurious, non-causal relationships that you don't care about, but I would not characterize these as Type I errors since there is a real statistical relationship between the variables. Consider a scenario looking at the effect of treatment, sex, and outcome - suppose males and females tend to choose different treatments for some disease, and that they also tend to have different outcomes regardless of treatment. One might find an association between treatment and outcome, but this effect is completely mediated by sex of the patient, with the choice of treatment actually having no effect independent of sex.

A Type I error represents a "mistake", incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis when it's actually true. To find that treatment is significantly associated with outcome is not a Type I error, as the null hypothesis that both treatment groups have identical outcome is not actually true. It's a correct answer to the question being asked, the fact that there are confounders which make that question less meaningful does not make the answer "wrong" - there *really is* a statistical association between treatment and outcome, regardless of how that's mediated by other variables.

Failure to account for confounders represents a failure to properly specify the hypothesis test to look for the interesting, independent effects you want; getting a misleading but statistically correct answer to a poorly specified hypothesis test is not a Type I error. There's certainly a danger of misinterpreting the association and making another kind of error in understanding, but failure to account for confounders is more of an error in the hypothesis specification, rather than an error in the result of hypothesis test - you're getting the correct answer to the wrong question, but a Type I error is categorically a "wrong answer".

Comment: Thanks for responding in this way, based on an accurate interpretation of confounding in RCTs. Your explanation of the distinction between random error and confounding agrees with reasoning that I used myself a day or so ago to try to convince myself that there is a distinction. However, I remain troubled by the approach that is commonly taken to explaining the source of random error. What imbalance has, for example, caused a difference in means to be sufficiently high to achieve statistical difference, wrongly so? Accidents (so-called) happen with a cause.

Comment: @Purist I'm not sure I follow your comment, but for me, whether or not confounding can result in a Type I error is a bit of a semantic distinction. A small imbalanced dataset can lead to spurious associations that would disappear when conditioned on the confounding factor - confounders can certainly lead to erroneous conclusions, whether or not those are Type I errors specifically.

Comment: @ Nuclear Hoagie You say, "whether or not confounding can result in a Type I error is a bit of a semantic distinction." What do you now mean? What causes a Type I error?

Comment: @Purist Ideally, a Type I error is a result of random sampling and getting "unlucky". An appropriate hypothesis test will reject the null either when it's actually false, or when you have an unusual sample that makes it look that way. At an alpha of 0.05, 5% of null hypotheses will be rejected when they are actually true, simply due to an unlucky sample. The only way you can be absolutely sure you never reject a true null hypothesis is by never rejecting any null.

Comment: @ Nuclear Hoagie. Thanks for sharing the traditional explanation of how to interpret a Type I error. I am really trying to probe a bit deeper and see if we can find a more informative explanation than "luck" or, as others call it, "chance" for this type of error.

Comment: @Purist Chance is a reasonable explanation for many Type I errors - you specify alpha knowing full well that alpha x 100% of true null hypothesis will be rejected. Null hypothesis rejected this way aren't special, they're by definition no different than any other true null hypothesis. You could look at nominal vs. empirical error rate for certain tests, but that will just explain the quantity of Type I errors you get, rather than offer an explanation for any individual error.

Comment: @ Nuclear Hoagie Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's talk about what you mean by "confounding". If you mean common causes of the treatment and outcome, then there is no confounding in randomized controlled trials. If you mean the more technical definition of open backdoor paths between the treatment and outcome, due, e.g., to loss to follow-up, conditioning on a collider, noncompliance, or measurement error, then there may indeed be confounding in a randomized trial. I'll assume you mean the latter.

A hypothesis test can be used to test any hypothesis. The validity of that the conclusions of the test depends on factors that link the hypothesis to the test used. However, that link isn't always as tight as it might seem. For example, to compare two independent means, you might use an independent samples t-test. Under certain assumptions, the t-test is a valid test of the difference in means. However, some people also use the Mann-Whitney U-test as a test for the difference in means (e.g., when the data do not appear to meet the assumptions of the t-test). But strictly speaking, the Mann-Whitney U-test is not a test for the difference in means and does not even consider the means in its formulation. The U-test might yield a nominal type I error rate in some circumstances and a different type I error rate in others.

The reason I wanted to disconnect the test from the hypothesis being tested is that in a treatment comparison study (randomized or observational), the estimand being tested is not always immediately obvious. One might think that the difference in outcome means, $\tau_{DOM}=E[Y|A=1]-E[Y|A=0]$ is the quantity being estimated and therefore the focus of the hypothesis test, but actually, the quantity of most interest is the causal quantity $\tau^*=E[Y^1]-E[Y^0]$, where $Y^a$ is the potential outcome under treatment level $a$. In the absence of confounding, $\tau_{DOM}=\tau^*$, so any valid test for $\tau_{DOM}$ is a valid test for $\tau^*$. However, in the presence of confounding, $\tau_{DOM}\ne\tau^*$, so a valid test for $\tau_{DOM}$ may not be a valid test for $\tau^*$.

How this relates to your question is that you can still use a test for $\tau_{DOM}$ as a test for $\tau^*$; it just won't be a valid test in the sense that the type I error rate will not be nominal. There is a decoupling between the hypothesis being tested, $H_0: \tau^* = 0$, and the method used to test it (i.e., a test based on $\tau_{DOM}$, like a t-test). So it is true that confounding can make a test for $\tau^*$ that is based on $\tau_{DOM}$ have a type I error that is not nominal. In that sense, the answer to your question is "yes".

However, using $\tau_{DOM}$ to test $\tau^*$ does not always lead to increased type I error rates. For example, if you are doing a one-sided test to test the null hypothesis that $\tau^* \le 0$ (i.e., because you are doing a non-inferiority study), if $\tau_{DOM} < \tau^*$ due to confounding, then the type I error will *decrease* (i.e., because you will almost always fail to reject the null hypothesis). For a two-sided test of $\tau^*=0$ where the null hypothesis is actually true, confounding will always increase the type I error compared to a circumstance without confounding.